# The Jquery script maybe is not working so my buttons are not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am creating an MVC calculator using Jquery. But the buttons are not functioning but the calculation is working fine after I typed it in the textbox and after I click the Equal button. That's weird. The Equal button works but the other buttons won't.

This is the code in my Controller:

```
 public string GetResult(string str)
    {
        List<char> symbleList = new List<char>();
        char[] charSymble = { '+', '-', '*', '/' };
        string[] st = str.Split(charSymble);
        for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
        {
            if (str[i] == '+' || str[i] == '-' || str[i] == '*' || str[i] == '/')
            {
                symbleList.Add(str[i]);
            }
        }
        double result = Convert.ToDouble(st[0]);
        for (int i = 1; i < st.Length; i++)
        {
            double num = Convert.ToDouble(st[i]);
            int j = i - 1;
            switch (symbleList[j])
            {
                case '+':
                    result = result + num;
                    break;
                case '-':
                    result = result - num;
                    break;
                case '*':
                    result = result * num;
                    break;
                case '/':
                    result = result / num;
                    break;
                default:
                    result = 0.0;
                    break;
            }
        }
        return result.ToString();
    }
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (Request["txt"] != null)
        {
            if (Request["txt"][Request["txt"].Length - 1] == '+' || Request["txt"][Request["txt"].Length - 1] == '-' || Request["txt"][Request["txt"].Length - 1] == '*' || Request["txt"][Request["txt"].Length - 1] == '/')
            {
                ViewBag.flag = 0;
                ViewBag.result = Request["txt"];
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.result = GetResult(Request["txt"]);
                ViewBag.flag = 1;
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

This is the code in my Index View:

```
<script src="~jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#txt").keypress(function (e) {
        if (String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode).match(/[^0-9+-/*]/g)) return false;
    });
    $("#txt").height("40px").width("312px");
    $("#b0").click(function () {
        var x = document.getElementById("txt").value;
        if (x == "0") {
            $("#txt").val("0");
        } else {
            $("#txt").val(x + "0")
        }
    });
    $("#b1").click(function () {
        var x = document.getElementById("txt").value;
        if (x == "0") {
            $("#txt").val("1");
        } else {
            $("#txt").val(x + "1")
        }
    });
    $("#b2").click(function () {
        var x = document.getElementById("txt").value;
        if (x == "0") {
            $("#txt").val("2");
        } else {
            $("#txt").val(x + "2")
        }
    });
    $("#b3").click(function () {
        var x = document.getElementById("txt").value;
        if (x == "0") {
            $("#txt").val("3");
        } else {
            $("#txt").val(x + "3")
        }
    });
    $("#b4").click(function () {
        var x = document.getElementById("txt").value;
        if (x == "0") {
            $("#txt").val("4");
        } else {
            $("#txt").val(x + "4")
        }
    });
    $("#b5").click(function () {
        var x = document.getElementById("txt").value;
        if (x == "0") {
            $("#txt").val("5");
        } else {
            $("#txt").val(x + "5")
        }
    });
    $("#b6").click(function () {
        var x = document.getElementById("txt").value;
        if (x == "0") {
            $("#txt").val("6");
        } else {
            $("#txt").val(x + "6")
        }
    });
    $("#b7").click(function () {
        var x = document.getElementById("txt").value;
        if (x == "0") {
            $("#txt").val("7");
        } else {
            $("#txt").val(x + "7")
        }
    });
    $("#b8").click(function () {
        var x = document.getElementById("txt").value;
        if (x == "0") {
            $("#txt").val("8");
        } else {
            $("#txt").val(x + "8")
        }
    });
    $("#b9").click(function () {
        var x = document.getElementById("txt").value;
        if (x == "0") {
            $("#txt").val("9");
        } else {
            $("#txt").val(x + "9")
        }
    });
    $("#div").click(function () {
        var x = document.getElementById("txt").value;
        var y = x.slice(-1)
        if (y == "/" || y == "+" || y == "*" || y == "-") { } else {
            $("#txt").val(x + "/")
        }
    });
    $("#multy").click(function () {
        var x = document.getElementById("txt").value;
        var x = document.getElementById("txt").value;
        var y = x.slice(-1)
        if (y == "/" || y == "+" || y == "*" || y == "-") { } else {
            $("#txt").val(x + "*")
        }
    });
    $("#sub").click(function () {
        var x = document.getElementById("txt").value;
        var x = document.getElementById("txt").value;
        var x = document.getElementById("txt").value;
        var y = x.slice(-1)
        if (y == "/" || y == "+" || y == "*" || y == "-") { } else {
            $("#txt").val(x + "-")
        }
    });
    $("#add").click(function () {
        var x = document.getElementById("txt").value;
        var x = document.getElementById("txt").value;
        var x = document.getElementById("txt").value;
        var x = document.getElementById("txt").value;
        var y = x.slice(-1)
        if (y == "/" || y == "+" || y == "*" || y == "-") { } else {
            $("#txt").val(x + "+")
        }
    });
    $("#dot").click(function () {
        var x = document.getElementById("txt").value;
        var y = x.slice(-1)
        if (y == ".") { } else {
            $("#txt").val(x + ".")
        }
    });
    $("#ce").click(function () {
        var x = document.getElementById("txt").value;
        $("#txt").val(x.substring(0, x.length - 1))
    });
});
</script>
<style>
body {
    background-image: url("Image/images.jpg");
}

#d1 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 340px;
    width: 340px;
}
</style>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<center>
<div id="d1">
@using (@Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home"))
    {
        <table style="height:25%;border:thick">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">
                    <center>
                        <h2>My Calculator</h2>
                    </center>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">@Html.TextBox("txt", (string)ViewBag.result)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" id="b7" value="7" style="height:40px;width:75px" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="b8" value="8" style="height:40px;width:75px" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="b9" value="9" style="height:40px;width:75px" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="div" value="/" style="height:40px;width:75px" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" id="b4" value="4" style="height:40px;width:75px" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="b5" value="5" style="height:40px;width:75px" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="b6" value="6" style="height:40px;width:75px" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="multy" value="*" style="height:40px;width:75px" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" id="b1" value="1" style="height:40px;width:75px" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="b2" value="2" style="height:40px;width:75px" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="b3" value="3" style="height:40px;width:75px" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="sub" value="-" style="height:40px;width:75px" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" id="b0" value="0" style="height:40px;width:75px" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="dot" value="." style="height:40px;width:75px" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="add" value="+" style="height:40px;width:75px" /></td>
                <td><input type="submit" id="eq" value="=" style="height:40px;width:75px" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="button" id="ce" value="CE" style="height:40px;width:155px" />
                </td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="reset" id="re" value="Clear" style="height:40px;width:155px" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">
                    <center>
                        <h2>Result : @ViewBag.result</h2>
                    </center>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    }
</div>
</center>
```

Here is the picture of the calculator:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KARCi.jpg

There is no error message, my debugging mode is on.

It run smoothly but again buttons don't work.

Comment: any errors in the browsers **developer** tools console

Comment: why do you have `~` in your script? here in `<script src="~/jquery-1.12.4.min.js">`

Comment: check your browser developer console while running your code and if any error occur post that error in your question

Comment: u dont have $(document).ready(....

Comment: @JaromandaX no errors.

Comment: @ShadowFiend even do I deleted it, it still didn't work.

Comment: @AlivetoDie there is no error.

Comment: @user1428716 where should I put it? I think it will still work without that? I am not sure though.

Comment: which browser are you using?

Comment: @Amit Google Chrome.

Comment: Did you change your script src as mentioned by @ShadowFiend above. Your code is fine and works.

Comment: @Amit it works in your computer?

Comment: @Amit yes I tried changing the script. it still doesn't work. :(

Comment: Yes..And I changed nothing. Whatever I changed was to refactor code.

Comment: Just check if your jquery file is available in the browser.As pointed by others as well, code is fine.

Comment: I don't knowwww why it is not workinggg to me. I am using Visio 2017 Enterprise, MVC 5. 

What kind of view did you choose?

Comment: @Amit How to do that Sir?

Comment: I used mvc sample project. Pasted your code on Index controller, and Index view and checked with that.

Comment: Press F12. Click Network tab. Press Ctrl + F5. Reload the page. Check if jquery is loading fine.

Comment: Okay, maybe I should restart my laptop and try it. @Amit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154805/discussion-between-joseph-carlo-and-amit).

Comment: @Amit still not working. :(

Comment: Your code is completely fine, as confirmed by few more in comments. Change jquery src to <script src="~/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script> Press F12. Click Network tab. Press Ctrl + F5. Reload the page. Check if jquery is loading fine. – Also, you can clear your browser cache. Press ctrl + F5. Or download firefox and try in that.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are including all buttons in a `BeginForm`. The default behavior of a `input type="button"` in a form is `submitting` the form.

So on each click on the buttons, you are submitting the form and your `click` handlers are ignored.

You should call `e.preventDefault();` at the start of each `click` handlers and declare each `click` handler like this:

```
$("#b8").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // code of your handler
});
```